# JMeter: Oauth 2.0 Token Generation- Getting Timed Out

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jmeter, postman, clientcredential

I am trying to do API Testing by JMeter in two steps:

**1. Generate Acess Token**

***Here, the authentication request is getting timed out.***

Authentication Type: OAuth2.0
Grant Type- Client Credentials

I am passing the token URL and grant_type, client_id and client_secret in the Parameters section like this:

[image]

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

**2. Hit the API with the fetched token**
I am able to hit this with a token generated from POSTMAN.
Also in POSTMAN, I am able to authenticate properly. I tried recording the POSTMAN script but the authentication flow is not getting recorded. Just the GET API is working.

Is there any way to get the token in JMeter? or any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Given you send the same requests you should get the same responses so capture the requests originating from JMeter and Postman using an external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and compare the them.

The requests must be exactly the same including:

- [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
- Request Body
- [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Inspect the requests and amend JMeter's configuration so the request would be 100% equal to what Postman sends.

Also it's possible to [record Postman request or collection execution using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

And last but not the least check [HTTP Proxy settings for Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/), it might be the case you need to use a proxy server for accessing the authorization endpoint and the connection to the application under test is direct, Postman has proxy configured and JMeter doesn't, if this is the case - perform [JMeter Proxy configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) again to match 100% Postman settings.

Comment: You were right, I added the proxy server for authorization and it worked. Thank you so much.
But the next difficulty is to run these scripts from Blazemeter which failed (Connection timed out) when I tried. 
I tried adding the load generator's IP (Blazemeter) but it also didn't work. 
Can you suggest something for this problem?

Comment: If the product you're trying to test is not accessible from the Internet I think you will need to go for the [Private Location](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421655-Creating-a-Private-Location)

Comment: this is the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: Connect to jmeter-plugins.org:443 timed out
 at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:100)
 ........
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to jmeter-plugins.org:443 timed out
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:545)
 ......